# Android Webview doesn't load

Tags: android, slider

I have a problem with Android Web view.
The slider work fine with Apple but doesn't load on Android WebView.

Can anyone help? www.pgc-usa.net/ivynails

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by slider. Please give more details

Answer (score 0):

I think I know. Web views in Android by default do not have JavaScript enabled. This is because there is someway it can do harm to the app. To enable it though it takes two lines

```
WebSettings webSettings = yourWebview.getSettings();
yourWebview.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

You can also set it so that links that are clicked open in the web view. ( Otherwise they open in browser.) to add this you just add

```
yourWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

All that together will make it come to this:

```
    WebView yourWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebview);
yourWebview.loadUrl("http://www.pgc-usa.net/ivynails");
WebSettings webSettings = yourWebviewgetSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
yourWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

You can find out more by visiting this page on the Android developer site by clicking [this link.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: Thank for your answer, im still a newbie. can you tell me where to insert the given code?? Thanks again

Comment: @pchau It really doesn't matter, as long as it is below where you initialize your web view. Although, if you want your code to be organized you should probably put it directly under the load url.

Comment: I'm so sorry but when I copy and copy the code above to my jssor.slider.mini.js it said code error... Can I have a more details instruction.

Comment: @pchau Sorry I did not provide enough detail. You do not add the code to a JavaScript file. You add the code under "WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web)" in your Android file.

Comment: Oh I dont have the android file. I download the package from "jssor" and follow there instruction to insert the slider....

Comment: @pchau Can you give me a link to this jssor so I can figure it out?

Comment: I dowload the package from www.jssor.com. And my site is ivynailslima.com

Comment: @pchau Are you creating an Android app.. If so, do you know what an activity is. If you do, what is the name of the activity you are working in?

Comment: @pchau I have created a video tutorial at this link. Click on the link below to watch it. [Click here to watch video](https://youtu.be/Px1LGUQfF-Q)